# Some php coding about array_search with unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

i want to find a key value from a array, if not exist then insert a array set into a array list

If i search blue, it will return Y
But if i search green, return N

```
$people = array(
  0 => array(
'name' => 'John',
'fav_color' => 'green'
 ),
1=> array(
  'name' => 'Samuel',
  'fav_color' => 'blue'
)
);
$found_key = array_search('green', array_column($people, 'fav_color'));

if($found_key){
    print_r("Y");
}else{
    print_r("N");
}
```

Expect search blue or green return Y

Comment: The key of the `$people`array is contains the values `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per note written in the documentation of [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

> **Warning:** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   [Booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use [the === operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

In Your case, `green` value has index 0. In if statement 0 means false. To get this rid of this problem, you need to strict type check the value returned by array_search as below.

```
if ($found_key !== false) { // strict type check
    print_r("Y");
} else {
    print_r("N");
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Gqmo2)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `in_array()` function also.

```
$people = array(
        0 => array(
      'name' => 'John',
      'fav_color' => 'green'
       ),
      1=> array(
        'name' => 'Samuel',
        'fav_color' => 'blue'
      )
      );

      $found_key = in_array('green', array_column($people, 'fav_color'));
      if($found_key){
          print_r("Y");
      }else{
          print_r("N");
      }
```